# jQuery Autocomplete on Dynamically added rows(Using Javascript)

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, html, jquery-autocomplete

Below is the code I am using to dynamically create rows in  HTML page.

```
 function addRow(tableID) {

        var table = document.getElementById(tableID);

        var rowCount = table.rows.length;
        var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);

        var colCount = table.rows[0].cells.length;

        for(var i=0; i<colCount; i++) {

            var newcell = row.insertCell(i);

            newcell.innerHTML = table.rows[0].cells[i].innerHTML;
            //alert(newcell.childNodes);
            switch(newcell.childNodes[0].type) {
                case "text":newcell.childNodes[0].value = "";
                        break;
                case "checkbox":
                        newcell.childNodes[0].checked = false;
                        break;
                case "select-one":
                        newcell.childNodes[0].selectedIndex = 0;
                        break;
            }
        }
    }

    function deleteRow(tableID) {
        try {
        var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
        var rowCount = table.rows.length;

        for(var i=0; i<rowCount; i++) {
            var row = table.rows[i];
            var chkbox = row.cells[0].childNodes[0];
            if(null != chkbox && true == chkbox.checked) {
                if(rowCount <= 1) {
                    alert("Cannot delete all the rows.");
                    break;
                }
                table.deleteRow(i);
                rowCount--;
                i--;
            }

        }
        }catch(e) {
            alert(e);
        }
    }
```

Below is the snippet from the HTML document calling the jQuery & addRow & autocomplete functionality,

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="addbox.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.4.2.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src="jquery.autocomplete.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery.autocomplete.css" />

<script type="text/javascript">
$().ready(function() {
$("#1").autocomplete("autocomplete.php",{
width: 260,
matchContains: true,
//mustMatch: true,
//minChars: 0,
//multiple: true,
//highlight: false,
//multipleSeparator: ",",
selectFirst: false
}); 
});
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$().ready(function() {
$("#3").autocomplete("autocomplete1.php",{
width: 260,
matchContains: true,
//mustMatch: true,
//minChars: 0,
//multiple: true,
//highlight: false,
//multipleSeparator: ",",
selectFirst: false
}); 
});
```

Here is the function for adding the row button & the table where we're associating the autocomplete with an id,

```
<input type="text" name="sub" size="76" /><br/><br/>
<INPUT type="button" value="Add Row" onclick="addRow('dataTable')" />

<INPUT type="button" value="Delete Row" onclick="deleteRow('dataTable')" />
<table border="1" cellpadding="10" id="data">
<tr>
```

Particulars
   Quantity
   UOM
   Unit Price

Tax

```
<table id="dataTable">
<TR>
        <TD ><INPUT type="checkbox" name="chk"/></TD>
        <TD ><INPUT type="text" name="par[]"size="20" id="3" /></TD>
        <TD><INPUT type="text" name="qua[]" size="5"/></TD>
    <TD><INPUT type="text" name="uom[]" size="5"/></TD>
    <TD><INPUT type="text" name="un[]" size="5"/></TD>
```

The auto-complete works *only* for the first input which is displayed by default. It doesn't work at all for additional row(s) which are added using the addrow function. As you can see we've associated id="3" for the input box having name par[]. We believe the problem could be there. Any assistance is much appreciated. Thanks !

Comment: never write html tag with uppercase.

Comment: Case doesn't matter unless it's xhtml. As far as why autocomplete isn't working, are you assigning the same id to additional rows as the first row?

Comment: For the first row I have given an id=3 in my main html file. The additional rows which are created using the Javascript addrow function do not have an id. How can we provide an id for the Javascript addrow function so that each row has unique id OR how can we have a single id for the AddRow function i.e irrespective of the number of rows added, they all have the same id.

Comment: We have solved this to a certain extent by using the following code inside the for loop of the addRow Javascript function.  `$().ready(function() {
$(":input").autocomplete("autocomplete1.php",{
width: 260,
matchContains: true,
selectFirst: false
});
});`                                                                 But this enables auto-complete for all input boxes. I merely need auto-complete to work for the second column which is having the attribute name "par[]"`

Answer (score 0):

the solution is easy, replace the id for a class and then put this class instead of `:input` in your addrow code, like:

```
$(function(){
    $('.autocomplete').autocomplete({source: 'autocomplete.php'});
});
```

i hope it helps you.